# Avada Theme Causing Issue with Bootstrap Breakpoints

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Avada 5.0.6 and it seems that the break point that is destroying my bootstrap grid.  The mobile responsiveness break point is 800 pixels wide.  However, according to the bootstrap documentation col-sm-* starts at 768 pixels.  So my grid should still work when I emulate a screen 800px wide.  But it doesn't, it puts the two divs on top of each other (picture at the bottom).

My HTML:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 phonenumbers">
    <h2>Phone numbers:</h2>
    <p>555-555-555</p>
    <p>555-555-555</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 email">
    <h2>Email:</h2>
    <p>info@test.ca</p>
    <p>careers@test.ca</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <h1>Connect with Us!</h1>
    <p></p>
    [contact-form-7 id="23" title="Contact Us Form"]
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.phonenumbers {
    margin-left: 35%;

}
.email {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      .phonenumbers {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .email {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
```

The desktop look:

[image]

The mobile look:

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you remove Avada theme?

Comment: When I do it in normal HTML with media queries, it does work.

Comment: The phone number + email will be on left and contact on right? This is what you want?

Comment: If you inspect `.phonenumbers` and `.email` is there any css applied to them from the theme like this `width: 100%!important;` at the 800px breakpoint? I don't have access to the theme but on sites that use it that seems to be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Avada, you can adjust everything, including breakpoints. It's default is not matched with Bootstrap's `768px`, it is `800px`. You can easily change it:

1. In **WP Admin Sidebar** select **Avada**
2. Select **Theme Options**
3. In Fusioon Avada 5.0.6 left-side menu select **Responsive**
4. Adjust **Header Responsive Breakpoint** and/or **Site Content Responsive Breakpoint** with range selects to your needs.

[image]

Comment: I did it, and still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 phonenumbers">
    <h2>Phone numbers:</h2>
    <p>555-555-555</p>
    <p>555-555-555</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 email">
    <h2>Email:</h2>
    <p>info@test.ca</p>
    <p>careers@test.ca</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <h1>Connect with Us!</h1>
    <p></p>
    [contact-form-7 id="23" title="Contact Us Form"]
    </div>
```

Live JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/uqpdb6sL/